# Django returns 404 after using restframework into existing project

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have working project ready, I am adding REST API for APIViews for like functionality after adding API into URL it is giving 404

Views.py

```
class PostLikeAPIToggle(APIView):
authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request, id=None, format=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    url_ = obj.get_absolute_url() 
    user = self.request.user
    updated = False
    liked = False

    if user.is_authenticated():
        if user in obj.likes.all():
            liked = False
            obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            liked = True
            obj.likes.add(user)
        updated = True
    data = {
        "updated" : updated,
        "liked" : liked
    }
    return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from posts import views
from rest_framework import routers
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='list'),
url(r'^create/$', views.post_create, name='create_post'),
url(r'^(?P<id>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<id>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='post_update'),
url(r'^api/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/like/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like-api-toggle'),
url(r'^(?P<id>[\w-]+)/like/$', views.PostLikeToggle.as_view(), name='like-toggle'),
url(r'^(?P<id>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.post_delete),]
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_location,
                    null=True,
                    blank=True, 
                    height_field="height_field", 
                    width_field = "width_field")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True, related_name = 'post_likes')
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

def get_api_like_url(self):
    return reverse("posts:like-api-toggle", kwargs={"id": self.id})

def get_like_url(self):
    return reverse("posts:like-toggle", kwargs={"id": self.id})



class Meta:
    ordering = ["-timestamp" , "-updated" ]
```

While I am redirecting 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1/like

it giving me 404 please help

Comment: How about removing the `api/` from `r'^api/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/like/$'` ?

Comment: so it will be like
url(r'^(?P<id>[\w-]+)/like/$', views.PostLikeToggle.as_view(), name='like-toggle'),

its working but i need using rest_api

Comment: Where do you get that error? In a template? Or when you hardcode the URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: using hardcoded in the browser address bar

Comment: ΟΚ. Could you show the root `urls.py`, please ?

Comment: from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from Home import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.Home),
    url(r'^feedback/$',views.Feedback),
    url(r'^contact/',include("contacts.urls", namespace='contacts')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
    

]

Comment: Please, delete your comment above and every time you are asked to provide large chunks of data, edit your answer and paste code there (instead of pasting in the comments). I have just posted an answer to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments above, this is happening cause of a wrong hardcoded URL by your side.

Instead of visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1/like` yous should be visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/api/1/like`.

Notice that inside your root `urls.py` you have this:

```
url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts'))
```

and inside the `posts.urls` you have:

```
url(r'^api/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/like/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like-api-toggle')
```

So, the correct structure of the URL is this:

```
[--- from root urls.py ----] [--from posts urls--]
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/      api/1/like/
```

You can also determine the url like this:

```
> ./manage.py shell

from django.urls import reverse

print(reverse('posts:like-api-toggle', kwargs={'id': 1}))
```

Note: You can also remove the `app_name = 'posts'` from your `app`'s `urls.py`. You are defining the `namespace` inside your root `urls.py` (`include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')`)

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Glad I could help!!